# icon according the zoom factor

Tags: google-maps-api-3

With the API version 3, How to change the size of an icon (created with MarkerImage) according to the zoom factor of the map ?
I suppose I must use scaledSize and map.getZoom() ?

Answer (score 1):

This is code cut and free hand written from the [api documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html) but it might give you an idea where to start

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
   yourMarker.setIcon("path to your icon here");
});
```

If you need to change all the icons on the map I would suggest putting them in an array and loop over them doing setIcon()

Comment: for me it's a bad approach: imagine the number of icons according the number of zoom steps !

Comment: @Bertaud Guess you could get the zoomfactor, check against it using mod and see if it is time to change the icon. The above is a bit of pseduo code anyway since it will set the same icon every time. But you could use it to check if the zoom factor is below/above a certain factor and then swap the icon.